# Locate/Extract Patches from an Image

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have an image(e.g. 60x60) with multiple items inside it. Items are in the shape of square boxes, with say 4x4 dimensions, and are **randomly** placed within the image. The boxes(items) themselves are created with **random** patterns, some random pixels switched on and others switched off. So, it could be the same box repeated twice(or more in case of more than 2 items) in the image or could be entirely different.

I'm looking to create a deep learning model that could take in the original image(60x60) and output all the patches in the image.

This is all I have for now, but I can definitely share more details as the discussion starts. I'd be interested to weigh in different options that can help me achieve this objective. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this using object detection. First I would train a network to detect those box like objects by cutting out patches of those objects. Then I would run a Faster R-CNN or something like this on it.

You might want to take a look at the stanford lecture on detection (slides here: http://cs231n.stanford.edu/slides/2017/cs231n_2017_lecture11.pdf).

Comment: Faster R-CNN is definitely a very good way, but I'd need annotated images for training, I assume?

Comment: You need a network that is able to classify the boxes correctly.